# how to add items in an array list while using jsp and servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'am making a shopping cart using JSP and servlet and I'am adding the items to cart through an arraylist from my database. I'am doing this by setting and getting the value of attributes of session.But it is adding only 1 value and after that the output is null.Please tell me how to resolve this problem.
This is my Cart.java page where elements are added to ArrayList

```
ArrayList al=null;
        HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {


            String id=request.getParameter("xyz");
            int i=Integer.parseInt(id);
            if (session.getAttribute("Il")==null)
            {

                al=new ArrayList();

            try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/cart","root","password");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from cake where id="+i+"");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                Item item=new Item();
                item.itemid=rs.getInt(1);
                String name=rs.getString(2);
                item.itemname=rs.getString(2);
                item.itemprice=rs.getString(3);
                al.add(item);


        }
            session.setAttribute("Il", al);
            con.close();
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("select.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
        }
            else
            {


                try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/cart","root","password");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from cake where id="+i+"");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                Item item=new Item();
                item.itemid=rs.getInt(1);
                String name=rs.getString(2);
                item.itemname=rs.getString(2);
                item.itemprice=rs.getString(3);
                al.add(item);


        }
            session.setAttribute("Il", al);
            con.close();
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("select.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
            }
```

This is my Cart.jsp page where all values are displayed.

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : Cart
    Created on : Jul 1, 2017, 10:36:09 AM
    Author     : hp-pc
--%>

<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="p1.Item"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Cart</title>
        <style>
            h1{
                float: right;
            }
          </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <%
          String name=(String)session.getAttribute("username");
            %>
            <h1>
                <%=name%>
            </h1>

                 <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> Select</th>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th> Name</th>
                    <th> Price</th>
                </tr>
                <form>
                  <%
                      System.out.println("testing.......................");
        ArrayList items=(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("Il");
        System.out.println("success........................"+items);
        Iterator it=items.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Item i=(Item)it.next();
    %>   
    <tr>
        <td>
                 <div class="radio">
                     <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"></label>
                 </div>
            </td>
        <td><%=i.itemid%></td>
        <td><%=i.itemname%></td>
        <td><%=i.itemprice%></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
      %>                 
                </form>
                 </table>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is adding only 1 value" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `al = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("Il");` after `} else {` :

```
        } else {
            al = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("Il"); // add this line
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

at least.